# skimage.transform.rescale changes datatype from uint8 to float64

Tags: python, image, types, scikit-image, rescale

When I use `skimage.transform.rescale` to reduce size of an image by 40% the datatype is converted from `uint8` to `float64`.

I can manually change the datatype but I don't want to have too many manual interventions in my code.

Is there any rescaling method keeping the datatype? I am also alternatively open to methods changing the datatype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the utility function [`img_as_ubyte`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.img_as_ubyte) to convert the rescaled image back to `uint8`.

#### Demo

```
In [26]: from skimage import util, data, transform

In [27]: img = data.moon()

In [28]: img.shape
Out[28]: (512, 512)

In [29]: img.dtype
Out[29]: dtype('uint8')

In [30]: res = util.img_as_ubyte(transform.rescale(img, 0.6))

In [31]: res.shape
Out[31]: (307, 307)

In [32]: res.dtype
Out[32]: dtype('uint8')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks for the edits as well. I did not know we should omit generic salutations (makes sense though) I hope thanking here is ok :)

Comment: Yeah, thanking in the comments is perfectly fine. My pleasure. You may want to have a look at [Why is it considered rude to say 'thanks in advance'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98149/why-is-it-considered-rude-to-say-thanks-in-advance)